# How to stop TopLink's logging in Weblogic application?

Tags: logging, jpa, weblogic, toplink

I'm developing an application in Weblogic 12.1 using TopLink as the JPA provider (the one that came with Weblogic).
My application uses a lot of 'SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT' queries, which usually fail and throw an exception. What happens next is that TopLink logs the exception, and it causes my log files to increase drastically.

I want to stop TopLink's logging. I've tried to use the following persistence.xml property:

```
<property name="toplink.logging.level" value="OFF"/>
```

but it seems to be ignored.

Any help please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TopLink uses EclipseLink as the JPA provider, so to disable logging you would set,

"eclipselink.loggging.level"="OFF"

You can also just disable exception logging using,

"eclipselink.logging.exceptions"="false"

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Comment: Yeah, I tried both TopLink's and EclipseLink's properties (and both the 'level' and the 'exceptions' properties). It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set TopLink logging levels in the persistence.xml file. However, when you accept the default logging integration with WebLogic Sever, those settings are ignored, and the logging configuration set in WebLogic Server is used.

You can override the default logging integration by setting `eclipselink.logging.logger` property name to a different setting,

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="DefaultLogger"/>
```